# Unable to read memory, private in a class

Tags: c++, class, exception

So I am studying Game development first year and this week we are learning about classes. I need to draw rectangles that when you hover over them they change color.

We get a framework from school, so I sadly don't know what everything does.

When I run this code it gives me an issue :

> Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
> **this** was nullptr.

I have searched on the internet, but as I am new to coding I don't understand a lot of it. Plus we have a given framework so some issues aren't really out there.

Here is the code, we were told what the names and the types were we had to use.

````
``` 
    class Light
    {
    private:
        Rectf m_Rect{};
        bool m_IsOn{ false };
        Color4f m_Color;
    public:
        Light(const Rectf rect, const Color4f color){}
    
        void Draw() 
        {
            Point2f Pos{};
            float size{25};
            //m_Color((rand() % 10) / 10.0f, (rand() % 10) / 10.0f, (rand() % 10) / 10.0f, 1.0f);
            //m_Color(1, 0, 1, 1.0f);
    
            if (m_IsOn == true)
            {
                Pos.x = size * 10;
                Pos.y = size;
                SetColor(1,0,1);
                m_Rect = Rectf{ Pos.x, Pos.y, size, size };
                std::cout << size;
            }
            else
            {
                Pos.x = size * 10;
                Pos.y = size;
                SetColor(1, 1, 1, 0.5f);
                m_Rect = Rectf{ Pos.x, Pos.y, size, size };
                std::cout << size + 1;
            }
        }
    
        bool IsHit(const Point2f pos)
        {
            
        }
    
        bool IsOn ()
        {
            if (g_MousePos.x <= m_Rect.left && g_MousePos.y <= m_Rect.bottom
                && g_MousePos.x >= m_Rect.left && g_MousePos.y >= m_Rect.bottom)
            {
                return m_IsOn == true;
            }
            else
            {
                return m_IsOn == false;
            }
        }
    };
    
    void Start()
    {
        // initialize game resources here
    }
    
    void Draw()
    {
        ClearBackground(0,0,0);
    
        // Put your own draw statements here
    
        Light* pLight{};
        pLight->Draw();
        delete pLight;
    };
```
````

When I open up the exception in the locals **this** sais this:

````
``` 
this    0x0000000000000000 <NULL>   Light *
m_Rect  <struct at NULL>    Rectf
m_IsOn  <Unable to read memory> 
m_Color {r=??? g=??? b=??? ...} Color4f
```
````

I genuinely do not know what I am doing wrong, I am sure that my code is all over the place. And I apologize, but I am open for criticism and possible ways I can do this better.
Keep in mind I am in my first year so I cannot possibly solve this problem using very complex things.

I thank you all so much :)!

Comment: `Light* pLight{};` you declared a pointer initialized to `nullptr` then you call `pLight->Draw();` without allocating memory for the object using new. Maybe you don't want to use a pointer at all. `Light light; light.Draw();` and no `delete` since there is no new.

Comment: Consider constructing a [mre]. The MRE is a powerful debugging technique. More often than not, you get part way into making a MRE and find you're reduced the noise around the bug enough to fix the problem yourself.